# How can I use left inverse to f(x)=3x format equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-curves

I want to solve linear equations as following.

$$f(x)= 3x^3 -4x^2 +3x -7$$
$$f(x)= 2x^3 -3x^2 +2x -1$$
$$f(x)= 1x^3 -7x^2 +1x -2$$

But these seem that there is no $y$.
How can I solve by using left inverse?

## Update :

$$3x^3 -4x^2 +3x -y  = 7$$

$$2x^3 -3x^2 +2x -y = 1 $$

Is this the same thing with above?
If yes, is this can be possible to appy left inverse or right inverse or svd ?

Comment: You can replace $f(x)$ by $y$. So there are two equations (non linear) and two unknowns. Methods developed for linear equations won't work here.

Comment: @zoli  : did you mean that we can not apply left inverse to above equations?

Comment: @daw what am i suppose to do?

Comment: What is the left inverse in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure. How about right inverse? Or SVD?

Comment: Let's assume that you could solve this equation based on "the left inverse". What would you do? Update you question with this attempted solution and someone will tell something. Where does this equation come from? Give some context, please.

Comment: @zoli : here is my reference. http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/i-am-looking-for-the-concept-about-all-in-one-curve-fitting/25146#25146

Comment: For me the referred Q and A are a complete mess. Why don't you ask your question in the Signal Processing Club?

Comment: @user5213616 It seems the user who responded to the post on the dsp.stackexchange interpreted your equations as $3x_3-4x_2+3x_1-7$ where $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and your function as being one of several variables as opposed to $3x^3-4x^2+3x^1-7$ where the function is of only one variable.  If it is indeed exponents on the $x$'s instead of indices, then this is as mentioned *not* linear.

Comment: This is about math not signal processing problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz : sorry i'm unfamiliar with math, would you please let me know more easly?

Comment: If you want to solve the question of where the two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ intersect, that is the same question as finding the roots of the function $\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)$ which does have a general solution for fourth degree and lower polynomials, but does *not* have a general solution for quintic and above.  If you are asking where three or more functions all intersect, you would check where they pairwise intersect and see if any are intersection points for all.  In general, there need not be a solution.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for letting me know that, so what am I suppose to do ? Is this not possible?

Comment: Given the answer you accepted, it looks like you are not looking for systems of one variable (as the notations $x^3$ and the tag "polynomials" hint), but systems of 3 variables indeed, If so, it would be useful to edit your question, to make it clear: in the RHS of the equations, $x_1$ instead of $x$, $x_2$ instead of $x^2$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments above, the equations you wrote are *not* linear (you have $x$ raised to powers that are neither $1$ nor $0$). You can still attempt to solve the system, however, using general techniques (which may not always succeed -- you are not guaranteed a priori that there are solutions that are real numbers).

Subtracting the second from the first, this becomes
$$
x^3 - x^2+x-6 = 0
$$
which has three roots (non-necessarily distinct), two of which at most being real numbers. A simple trick is first to see if "simple" solutions work: try $x=0,1,2,-1,-2$... Here, $2$ works, i.e. $x=2$ is a solution. Factoring, you get
$$
(x-2)(x^2+x+3) = 0
$$
Now, the roots of $x^2+x+3$ can be computed easily according to the usual method to find the roots to quadratic equations. Doing so (they are both complex, and not real), you get that the original equations amount to
$$
(x-2)\left(x-\frac{1+i\sqrt{11}}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1-i\sqrt{11}}{2}\right) = 0
$$
so the three only solutions are $\{2, \frac{1-i\sqrt{11}}{2}, \frac{1+i\sqrt{11}}{2}\}$ (and only one of them is a real number).

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is the "method of least squares". Suppose you have a variable $y$, of which you take a series of measurements. You know that $y$ depends non-linearly on a variable $x$ and, by taking two sets of measurements of $y$, you're able to determine two possible relationships for $y$. You would like to use this information so that - given a value of $y$ - you can find an approximation for $x$.

Here, the two possible relationships for $y$ are given by $f(x) = x^3 + \cdots$ and $f(x) = x^2 + \cdots$. In practice, these different answers might arise (for example) due to noisy data, or imperfect measurement devices.

Each of the two relationships is described by a parameter vector $H_1$ and $H_2$. In your example, $H_1 = (3, -4, 3, -7)$ and $H_2 ( 2, -3, 2, -1)$. What I mean, here, is that we can describe $f(x)$ as $y = H_1\cdot (x^3, x^2, x, 1)^T$ and $y = H_2 \cdot (x^3, x^2, x, 1)^T$

To solve, we follow what was done on the other page. For a given value $y$, an approximation to $x$ - we'll call it $\hat x$ - is given by:

$$\hat x = (H^TH)^{-1}H^T y$$

where 
$$
H = [H_1 ~H_2] = \left[\matrix{3& 2\\ -4& -3\\ 3& 2\\ -7& -1}\right]
$$
and $H^T$ is the transpose of $H$, and $(A)^{-1}$ is the inverse of the matrix $A$.

Comment: Yea thats as I knownthis way is celled as left inverse . And now I am looking for a way to apply my case.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue with your case? You haven't quite explained what the problem is.

Comment: My problem is looking for making one equation from multi equatons. as like above example.

Comment: Thanks for letting me I think yours is what I want answer very closely , then can I use your way to make one equation from 2 equations?

Comment: It depends what you're looking to solve for! Since you said *linear* problem, I assumed it was linear in the parameters (rather than linear in $x$). That means you'd be solving for an approximation to the vector $(1,x,x^2,x^3)^T$. 

OR

If the problem is *actually* nonlinear, then you should do what was mentioned above. Since $f(x) = x^3 + \cdots$ and $f(x) = x^2 + \cdots$, then $x^3 +\cdots = x^2 + \cdots$ so that by simplifying you get $x^3 - x^2+x-6=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll trying to that and let you know if any question  thanks

Comment: Do you know MATLAB commands to approximate x hat?